# How to update a task variable based on the task that triggered it

Tags: airflow

I'm pulling data from an API and putting into bigquery. I would like to dynamically change the bigquery table the data is loaded to. For example: A task calling the api for "list" data, should be added to the list table in bigquery.

Currently, I have 3 different dags. One for each API call. I wanted to condense them into one DAG, but i'm not sure how to dynamicly change the destination table in my load_to_bg task.

```py
#Config Variables

task1 = MailchimpToS3Operator(
        task_id='lists',
        mailchimp_conn_id = MC_CONN_ID,
        mailchimp_resource = 'lists',
        dag=dag
    )

task2 = MailchimpToS3Operator(
        task_id='camapaigns',
        mailchimp_conn_id = MC_CONN_ID,
        mailchimp_resource = 'campaigns'
        dag=dag
    )

task3 = MailchimpToS3Operator(
        task_id='memebers',
        mailchimp_conn_id = MC_CONN_ID,
        mailchimp_resource = 'members',
        dag=dag
    )

load_to_bq = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='gcp_to_bq',
        destination_project_dataset_table = "mailchimp.mailchimp_{}".format(mailchimp_resource),
        dag=dag
        )

[task1,task2,task3] >> load_to_bq
```

The destination_project_dataset_table should update to include the mailchimp_resource value from the task that triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a defined set of apis that you know in advance or you can query at run time, you can do the following:

```py
resources = [("resource name", "table to copy to")] # you can definitely call an api to get this resources list


with DAG("test_dag",schedule_interval="@daily") as dag:
    for res in resources:
        a = MailchimpToS3Operator(
            task_id=res[0],
            mailchimp_conn_id=MC_CONN_ID,
            mailchimp_resource=res[0],
            dag=dag
        )

        b = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id='gcp_to_bq_'+res[0],
            destination_project_dataset_table = "mailchimp.mailchimp_"+res[1],
            dag=dag
            )

        a >> b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to "Branching" in Airflow. 
One way to do this is by using the **BranchPythonOperator**. This operator only go down a certain path based on the result from the upstream task.

.
[image]

Refer from a very good read: https://medium.com/@guillaume_payen/use-conditional-tasks-with-apache-airflow-98bab35f1846
Airflow docs: http://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=branch#branching.